# Can any one provide me a sample of using CreateHatchBrush

Tags: c++, gdi, thumbnails

I want to draw a shadow around a thumbnail in my software.
It seems CreateHatchBrush can help but I do not know how to use it, can anyone provide me a sample in C++?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option would be to use [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798(VS.85).aspx) to do this.  Here's a quick and dirty shadow rendering sample:

```
void Render( HDC hdc )
{
    Graphics gr( hdc );
    Image image( L"sample.jpg" );
    const int SHADOW_OFFSET = 7;

    //
    // draw shadow
    //
    SolidBrush shadow( Color( 190, 190, 190 ) );
    Rect rc( 50, 50, image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight() );
    rc.Offset( SHADOW_OFFSET, SHADOW_OFFSET );
    gr.FillRectangle( &shadow, rc );

    //
    // draw the image
    //
    gr.DrawImage( &image, 50, 50, image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight() );

    //
    // draw a border
    //
    Pen border( Color( 0, 0, 0 ), 1 );
    rc.Offset( -SHADOW_OFFSET, -SHADOW_OFFSET );
    gr.DrawRectangle( &border, rc );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a sample, but some hints on general usage of brushes in Windows.

`CreateHatchBrush()` returns a handle. You need to use that handle to make that brush the current brush in the Device Context you are using to render. Call the Device Context's `SetObject` function (plain Windows GDI calls version):

```
HDC myDC = GetDC (hWnd); //pass your window handle here or NULL for the entire screen  
HBRUSH hatchBrush = CreateHatchBrush (HS_DIAGCROSS, RGB (255,128,0));  
HBRUSH oldBrush = SelectObject (myDC, hatchBrush);  
//draw something here  
SelectObject (myDC, oldBrush); //restore previous brush  
ReleaseDC (myDC);
```